# How the rewards are incorporated into the learning process?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, stable-baselines

I have an environment in which I am trying to learn the system dynamics using [baseline3](https://stable-baselines.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/quickstart.html)  library. Since my example is quite big, I am using the following example to clarify the problem I have.

**The problems**

1. Where actually environment reword incorporate into the learning process?
2. Is there any upper and lower bound for the rewards?

My code:

```
from stable_baselines.common.policies import MlpPolicy
from stable_baselines.common.vec_env import DummyVecEnv
from stable_baselines import PPO2

env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
   

model = PPO2(MlpPolicy, env, verbose=1)
model.learn(total_timesteps=10000)

obs = env.reset()
for i in range(1000):
    action, _states = model.predict(obs)
    obs, rewards, dones, info = env.step(action)
    env.render()
```

I could not find any information regarding this yet.